# What counts as an "area of magical darkness" for the Blend into Shadows feat?

Tags: feats, dnd-3e, area-of-effect

The Blend Into Shadows feat from *Drow of the Underdark* reads

> **Benefit:** As a swift action, you can spend a use of your darkness spell-like ability to make a Hide check, even while being observed and without cover or concealment. You must be within 10 feet of an area of magical darkness. You also gain one additional daily use of your darkness spell-like ability.

What counts as an "area of magical darkness"?

Comment: Okey the edit was abit false here. I was asking what the word "Area" will count as, I only used the feat as an example. 
We have already established some grounds on this in the campaign. Misstake on my part to not make it clearer that I was asking for something specific. 
Once again I am only asking for the word area, This is still a viable thred, but the original question was for what the defenition of an area is.

Comment: You can edit your question into a form you think is more accurate by clicking on the 'edit' link.

Answer (score 1):

Magical darkness is the result of a spell, spell-like ability, or supernatural ability (collectively, a magical ability). The term “Area” has a defined meaning for magical effects, per the [Spell Descriptions > Area](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#area) rules.<sup>1</sup> These rules define how areas are measured and describes several sorts of typical areas. Note that most of them are actually three-dimensional shapes, that is, they have a volume rather than an area; nonetheless, Area is the name of the game term for these shapes.

So the area of magical darkness is exactly what the originating effect defines it as; it is the area of that effect. For example, [*darkness*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/darkness.htm) has an area of “a 20-foot radius,” which defines a sphere,<sup>2</sup> while [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/deeperDarkness.htm) has an area of “a 60-foot radius,” a (dramatically) larger sphere.

Blend into Shadows functions so long as you are within 20 feet of the area affected by one of these magical darkness effects. So in the case of *darkness*, Blend into Shadows effectively works in a 40-ft. radius of the center of the *darkness* effect (that is, within the *darkness* as well as outside it but still within 20 feet of the edge of the area).

1. <sup>Strictly speaking, an area of magical darkness could be created without using a spell or magical ability that references a spell, which means it does not reference any spell description. But I cannot think of any case where this occurs, and in any event these are the most applicable rules.</sup>
2. <sup>Note that it doesn’t matter how the *darkness* effect is created; this applies equally to both *darkness* spells from bards, clerics, sorcerers, wizards, and so on, as it does for the *darkness* spell-like ability of drow.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## What is magic?

We have some explicit definitions of what is and is not magical [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm).

> Extraordinary abilities are nonmagical...
>
> Supernatural abilities are magical...
>
> Usually, a spell-like ability works just like the spell of that name...

From [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/magicOverview.htm) we know that

> A spell is a one-time magical effect.

If spells are magical, then so are SLAs. Magic items are explicitly magic, because they have "magic" in the name.

## What is darkness?

Darkness is defined in the [Environment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#darkness) rules. However, only pitch black darkness is discussed there, which would make the spell *[darkness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/darkness.htm)* not be Darkness.

Since that's insane (and the feat explicitly makes the connection to the spell by giving you *darkness* uses) we can assume that effects with the [Darkness] descriptor are all considered darkness. Additionally, since the effect of *darkness* is:

> This spell causes an object to radiate shadowy illumination out to a 20-foot radius.

You could say that all shadowy illumination should be considered darkness. But by strict RAW, [shadowy illumination](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm) is a separate thing from darkness. The feat requires a little bit of interpretation to use, and I would recommend leaning in the direction that doesn't make the feat useless.